# PreferenceActivity with two SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How to create a preference screen which can save values in two different shared preferences ?

For example, in my PreferenceActivity my first preference is a CheckBoxPreference. The state of the checkbox is saved in "user_86_Prefs" sharedPreferences and the second preference is a ListPreference, and the state of the selected item is saved in "devicePrefs" sharedPreference.

in my PreferenceFragment I can only do

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("user_86_Prefs");
```

Actually the sharedPreference named "user_86_Prefs" is specific to the user connected on the app, and the "devicePrefs" is specific to the device.

Should I create another class which extends PreferenceFragment, and put the preferences specific to the device inside ? If yes, how can I have my two preferencesFragments in the same Activity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to create one class in wich you handle all your preferences.

```
public class MySharedPreferences{

    private static final String USER_PREF = "user_shared_pref";
    private static final String DEVICE_PREF = "device_shared_pref";

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserPref(Context ctx,String user_pref){
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(USER_PREF,user_pref);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getUserPref(Context ctx){
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(USER_PREF,"");
    }
}
```

Same thing for your device preferences ! And you juste need to do something like that to access it from other class/activity/fragment :

```
MySharedPreferences.setUserPref(this /* or whatever your context is*/,yourValue);
```

Comment: several users can connect to a smarpthone and I have a preference for each user : user_86_Prefs, user_87_Prefs, user_42_Prefs, user_24_Prefs, etc. user_86_Prefs for example is not a string, it is a sharedPreference which contains strings/int/... so I need to create another sharedpreference for the device itself, which gather preferences related to the smartphone.